# Can dark matter be isolated from baryonic matter?

Tags: thermodynamics, astronomy, dark-matter, galaxies, modified-gravity

[image]

The above is an image to test Verlinde's emergent gravity theory (2016, https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02269). The research team observered galaxies and masses beyond, used gravitational lensing (y-axis) set out against the distance from the centre of the galaxies (x-axis), and considered the galaxies as points (point mass) and with more detail (extended model). This image includes four graphs of galaxies of varied masses. The statistical uncertainty is 1 sigma.

I do not know if I interpreted it correctly, but I think that these graphs are meant to say: 'if (apparent) dark matter were completely isolated, then the strength of the gravitational lensing at distance R would be...' It is however more likely that the correct interpretation is: 'if this model is correct, then the strength of the gravitational lensing at distance R would be...', but then why would the graph decrease as it goes further away? There is after all more dark matter at the end of galaxies

Is it even possible that dark matter is completely isolated from baryonic matter? Does emergent gravity even allow this?

Source of image: Brouwer et al., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.03034.pdf

Comment: Dark matter and baryonic matter have separated in the [Bullet Cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Cluster).